# How To Validate Secure Traffic from Chrome with Element To Matrix.org on Linux

Tags: google, chrome, tcp, sniffer, ajax

Are you familiar with the Element chat system of https://app.element.io ? Are you familiar with its connections to Matrix.org (for a free account)? Is there a way that I can sniff this traffic on the OS when I hit the enter key on a message so that I can confirm that Google Chrome on Linux only sends this encrypted message to Matrix.org and no other locations? A colleague believed that Google Chrome would send this same encrypted message block of data back to Google or some dubious location.

Note, I'm using Lubuntu Linux 19.10 and the Google Chrome (not Chromium) is the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a packet sniffer (wireshark, tcpdump) to capture traffic, and the OS tools (netstat) to determine the network port used by the Chrome process (each Chrome tab is its own process). Then you simply pair the traffic from this process to its destinations.

But the premise is ridiculous. If Chrome wanted to secretly copy the data to its own servers so that it could try to break the encryption to read what you are sending (already ridiculous), then it would do it over its own process, and compress and batch the sending, so you would not be able to distinguish this traffic from other types of traffic. So, if this was happening, it would be very, very difficult to confirm that they were ***not*** doing that.

But it's always very difficult to prove a negative.